# Visual Studio - is there a repeat last command command or shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

This is a lark, as I'm pretty sure not, but just want to throw it out there, otherwise I can just use a macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such command -- there are no different working modes in VS as in vi. Your macro will have to run all the time though. And you might get your editor dirty ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I think you might be able to achieve a result similar to what you're looking for by using temporary macros. Here are the steps to create and use a temporary macro...

1. Press `CTRL+SHIFT+R` to begin recording a temporary macro.
2. Perform the command or set of commands you wish to repeat.
3. Press `CTRL+SHIFT+R` to stop recording the temporary macro.
4. Press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` to execute the temporary macro. Repeat this step as many times as you want to repeat the command(s).

Comment: Is there a way to record actions done through context menus such as surround with

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting this because you are a vi user, there is always [viEmu](http://www.viemu.com/)