# Visual Studio Code: How to use F4 to Repeat Last Action

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

What is the method to enable the use of F4 or other "ONE-KEY" press to repeat the last action in VS Code.
*A feature similar to the use of F4 under MS Word*.

This article: [Visual Studio Code command for "repeat last command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980406/visual-studio-code-command-for-repeat-last-command) does not answer this question and uses more than one (1) key.

Thanks

Comment: There was a macro solution which is as close to one key as you are going to get - you can use `F4` for the keybinding if you wish.  Otherwise there is no built-in way to rerun the last command, unless someone has written an extension to do it.

Comment: @Mark not sure if there is an extension available. Couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and I couldn't find a shortcut that words like F4 in MS Word. I was hoping to find the shortcut and edit it but there is no such command in VS code.

Answer drawn from this post: [Visual Studio - is there a repeat last command command or shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225784/visual-studio-is-there-a-repeat-last-command-command-or-shortcut)

Comment: Thanks. The other post is a 3 finger combination. It is a lot of manipulation if you want to do repeated operations several times with short gaps.

Comment: That linked answer is for Visual Studio.